# NSTask not working in Swift

Tags: swift2, xcode7, xctest

I am writing a swift XCTest and I need to assess a sub process. I want to call the terminal, pass the path of an applescript to the terminal and execute it.

I've imported both UIKit and Foundation in the swift test file. When I go to write a constant like: `let task = NSTask()` the NSClass is not referenced in the NSObject, and as a result I get a message that it is a

> Use of unresolved unidentifier NSTask

If I write `let pipe = NSPipe()` that is referenced and works. Why is NSTask inaccessible after importing UIkit and Foundation?

Comment: NSTask is not available on iOS

Comment: then that explains that. thanks @user3441734

Answer (score 3):

in swift 3.0 Apple changed NSTask API

To execute a cmd now is:

```
// Create a process (was NSTask on swift pre 3.0)
let task = Process()

// Set the task parameters
task.launchPath = "/bin/ls"
task.arguments = ["-laF@" , filePath]

// Create a Pipe and make the task
// put all the output there
let pipe = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe

// Launch the task
task.launch()

// Get the data
let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let output = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
print(output!)
```

Comment: Process() still says: “use of unresolved identifier Process” in swift 3 Xcode 8.1 (with foundation imported) any suggestions?

Comment: tested now under Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a) in:
1) an  OSX app: it works
2) a cocoa Terminal App: it works.

Comment: Indeed it does, I was developing in iOS which is why it would not work. My fault!

Comment: Why would Apple allow that to work in OSX and not iOS? We on the mobile side of the fence also need to access terminal commands in tests/other.

Comment: no, it's a design choice: no usual "process" in iOS, for al lot of reasons: performance, consummations, HW limitations and so on.

Comment: ^^ sorry, i was led astray by an errant article.